# How to have NUnit discover DLL in a sub-folder?

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, .net-core, nunit

We have created our first .Net Core(.Net 6) project, and creating our first tests for it an having some errors.

The tests DLL are in /Debug and the tested(referenced) DLL are in a subfolder of Debug("Central").

basically this:

```
Src
   /Central
           /Central.Application
Tests
     /Central
             /Central.Application.tests
Debug
     /Central.Application.tests.dll
     /Central
             /Central.Application.dll
```

(This might seem complex but the solution has more than 400 projects, some are dynamically loaded by directory(plugins))+

When I try to run tests in visual studio, I get:

```
Building Test Projects
Starting test discovery for requested test run
Test project Xms.Central.Application.Test does not reference any .NET NuGet adapter. Test discovery or execution might not work for this project.
It's recommended to reference NuGet test adapters in each test project in the solution.
========== Starting test discovery ==========
NUnit Adapter 4.2.0.0: Test discovery starting
NUnit failed to load E:\Dev\XXX\Debug\Central.Application.Test.dll
NUnit Adapter 4.2.0.0: Test discovery complete
No test is available in E:\Dev\XXX\Debug\Central.Application.Test.dll. Make sure that test discoverer & executors are registered and platform & framework version settings are appropriate and try again.
========== Test discovery finished: 0 Tests found in 373,2 ms ==========
Executing all tests in project: Central.Application.Test
========== Starting test run ==========
========== Test run finished: 0 Tests (0 Passed, 0 Failed, 0 Skipped) run in < 1 ms ==========
```

I've investigated a bit, and with adding `DumpXmlTestDiscovery` to my `.runSettings`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RunSettings>
    <RunConfiguration>
        <!-- x86 or x64 -->
        <!-- You can also change it from the Test menu; choose "Processor Architecture for AnyCPU Projects" -->
        <TargetPlatform>x64</TargetPlatform>
    </RunConfiguration>
    <NUnit>
        <DisableAppDomain>True</DisableAppDomain >
        <DumpXmlTestDiscovery>True</DumpXmlTestDiscovery>
        <DumpXmlTestResults>True</DumpXmlTestResults>
    </NUnit>
</RunSettings>
```

I've managed to extract the following diagnostics:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<NUnitXml>
<test-run id='0' name='Central.Application.Test.dll' fullname='E:\Dev\XXX\Debug\Central.Application.Test.dll' runstate='Runnable' testcasecount='0'>
   <test-suite type='Assembly' id='0-1000' name='Central.Application.Test.dll' fullname='E:/Dev/XXX/Debug/Central.Application.Test.dll' runstate='NotRunnable' testcasecount='0'>
      <environment framework-version='3.13.3.0' clr-version='6.0.4' os-version='Microsoft Windows 10.0.22000' platform='Win32NT' cwd='E:\Dev\XXX\Debug' machine-name='J4N-DESKTOP' user='Jaytonic' user-domain='J4N-Desktop' culture='fr-CH' uiculture='en-US' os-architecture='x64' />
      <settings>
         <setting name='SynchronousEvents' value='False' />
         <setting name='RandomSeed' value='430364106' />
         <setting name='SkipNonTestAssemblies' value='True' />
         <setting name='ProcessModel' value='InProcess' />
         <setting name='DomainUsage' value='Single' />
         <setting name='DefaultTestNamePattern' value='{m}{a}' />
         <setting name='WorkDirectory' value='E:\Dev\XXX\Debug' />
         <setting name='NumberOfTestWorkers' value='20' />
      </settings>
      <properties>
         <property name='_SKIPREASON' value='Unable to load one or more of the requested types.&#xD;&#xA;Could not load file or assembly &apos;Central.Application, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null&apos;. Le fichier spécifié est introuvable.&#xD;&#xA;  ----&gt; Could not load file or assembly &apos;Central.Application, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null&apos;. Le fichier spécifié est introuvable.' />
      </properties>
   </test-suite>
</test-run>
</NUnitXml>
```

I tought this was because it was in a subfolder, since it's something a bit different than the standard. But, as for our other projects, we have an app.config with the following content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <runtime>
      <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
          <probing privatePath="Central" />
      </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
</configuration>
```

Which was, at least in .Net 4.7.2, including the mentionned path in the search directory. But even with this, I get the same result.

Both my test project and my target DLL are in .Net 6

Any idea what I could be missing? I tried to clean everything and rebuild everything

**EDIT 1**
If I run this through resharper, I get the same kind of error:

```
2022.04.19 11:54:13.209   ERROR TestRunner: NUnitTestReporter Unable to load one or more of the requested types. Could not load file or assembly 'Central.Application, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'. Le fichier spécifié est introuvable. ----> Could not load file or assembly 'Central.Application, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'. Le fichier spécifié est introuvable.

--- EXCEPTION #1/1 [LoggerException]
Message = “
  TestRunner: NUnitTestReporter Unable to load one or more of the requested types.
  Could not load file or assembly 'Central.Application, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'. Le fichier spécifié est introuvable.
    ----> Could not load file or assembly 'Central.Application, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'. Le fichier spécifié est introuvable.
”
ExceptionPath = Root
ClassName = JetBrains.Util.LoggerException
HResult = COR_E_APPLICATION=80131600
StackTraceString = “
  at JetBrains.Util.ILoggerEx.LogMessage(ILogger this, LoggingLevel level, String message)
     at JetBrains.ReSharper.UnitTestFramework.Execution.TestRunner.Activation.ServerEndpoint.<>c__DisplayClass9_2.<TryRegisterHandler>b__3()
     at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.InnerInvoke()
     at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
     at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
     at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
     at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ExecuteWithThreadLocal(Task& currentTaskSlot)
     at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ExecuteEntry(Boolean bPreventDoubleExecution)
     at System.Threading.ThreadPoolWorkQueue.Dispatch()
”
```

If I try to run `dotnet test .\Central.Application.Test.dll`, it tells me(in french) that no tests have been  discovered in the assembly.

**Edit 2**
I managed to reproduce it here: https://github.com/jaytonic/ProjectRefIssue
Some constraints that I've:

- I've to keep this folder structure
- I've to keep the copy-local false

Comment: Just for the sake of completeness: does it work when executing `dotnet test Central.Application.Test.csproj`? And are you referencing `Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk`, `NUnit3TestAdapter` and `nunit`?

Comment: @mu88 Thank for the answer. I just tried the `dotnet test`, it just returns that not tests have been found. I'm reference Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk (17.1.0), NUnit (3.13.3), NUnit3TestAdapter (4.2.1)(and Moq 4.16.1)

Comment: Can you reduce it to a very small sample solution (preferably a GitHub repo)? That would make it easier

Comment: I managed to reproduce the issue here: https://github.com/jaytonic/ProjectRefIssue Some constraints that I've: I cannot change the folder structure and I cannot have the CopyLocal set to true.

Comment: @mu88 I completed the question with your question

Comment: That's freaking crazy: I can reproduce the issue with your repo, but not with mine ([see here](https://github.com/mu88/StackOverflow_NUnitTest)). Do you see the difference?

Comment: @mu88 I have the `<AppendTargetFrameworkToOutputPath>false</AppendTargetFrameworkToOutputPath>` in the test project, you do not, and everything get placed in the same directory(well duplicated in /Debug and /Debug/net6)

Comment: @mu88 by the way, I can't explain why, if you don't have the Directory.Build.targets, everything gets copied in the /Debug (including what was in /Debug/Central), even if we have the "CopyLocal" set to false

Comment: And `AppendTargetFrameworkToOutputPath` seems to be the culprit. When adding this line to my code, it fails.

Comment: @mu88 Actually, if you don't add the `AppendTargetFrameworkToOutputPath` but add 
 the  `<Private>False</Private>` inside the  ProjectReference, it fails again.